# Kotlin type inference on "supposedly" right types

Tags: kotlin, generics, type-inference, covariance

I am new to Kotlin and I was playing with it. I pretty much wanted to create a pretty basic event bus. So I came up with this

```
interface Event
interface EventListener<E : Event> {
    fun handle(event: E)
}

interface EventBus {
    fun <E : Event> registerListener(aClass: Class<E>, eventListener: EventListener<E>)
}

class MyBus() : EventBus {
    private val eventListeners: MutableMap<String, MutableList<EventListener<out Event>>> = mutableMapOf()

    constructor(listeners: List<Pair<Class<Event>, EventListener<Event>>>) : this() {
        listeners.forEach {
            registerListener(it.first, it.second)
        }
    }

    override fun <E : Event> registerListener(aClass: Class<E>, eventListener: EventListener<E>) {
        val key = aClass.name
        val listeners: MutableList<EventListener<out Event>> = eventListeners.getOrPut(key) { mutableListOf() }
        listeners.add(eventListener)
    }
}


val bus = MyBus(
    listOf(
        MyEvent::class.java to MyEventListener()
    )
)

class MyEvent : Event
class AnotherEvent : Event
class MyEventListener : EventListener<MyEvent> {
    override fun handle(event: MyEvent) {
    }
}
```

what happens is that when I try to create MyBus using the constructor accepting the list of pairs, I get

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is List<Pair<Class<MyEvent>,MyEventListener>> but List<Pair<Class<Event>,EventListener<Event>>> was expected
```

But if I change the constructor to be something like

```
constructor(listeners: List<Pair<Class<out Event>, EventListener<out Event>>>) : this() {
        listeners.forEach {
            registerListener(it.first, it.second)
        }
    }
```

adding out pretty much everywhere, then the MyBus constructor works, but the invocation to registerListener(..) breaks for the same exact reason as before. So the only way to solve this is to add "out"s also on registerListener function.

I suspect I'm doing something wrong here, but I don't know what precisely. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your `EventListener` to be able to consume `Event`s, then its type has to be *invariant* or *covariant* (not declared `out`). If it let you pass your `EventListener<MyEvent>` as if it were an `EventListener<Event>`, then your `MyBus` class might call `listener.handle(event)` on it with some `Event` that is not a `MyEvent`, such as `AnotherEvent`. Then you will get a `ClassCastException` when it tries to cast this `AnotherEvent` to `MyEvent`.

To be able to store different types of invariant EventHandlers, you will have to remove the variance restrictions by using star projection, and cast them when you retrieve them from the map. So make the map keys into class objects instead of just Strings. Since you will not have the help of the compiler when working with the star-projected types, you need to be careful that you are only adding an item to your MutableMap that is of the same type as the Class key that's associated with it. Then when you retrieve items, only cast to an invariant type.

The other part of your issue is that your constructor needs a generic type. Right now it works exclusively with `Event` so it can't handle subtypes of `Event`. Kotlin doesn't (yet?) support generic types for constructors so you have to do this with a factory function.

Here's an example of all the above.

```
class MyBus() : EventBus {
    private val eventListeners: MutableMap<Class<*>, MutableList<EventListener<*>>> = mutableMapOf()

    override fun <E : Event> registerListener(aClass: Class<E>, eventListener: EventListener<E>) {
        val listeners = retrieveListeners(aClass)
        listeners.add(eventListener)
    }

    private fun <E: Event> retrieveListeners(aClass: Class<E>): MutableList<EventListener<E>> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return eventListeners.getOrPut(aClass) { mutableListOf() } as MutableList<EventListener<E>>
    }
}

// Factory function
fun <E : Event> myBusOf(listeners: List<Pair<Class<E>, EventListener<E>>>): MyBus {
    return MyBus().apply {
        listeners.forEach {
            registerListener(it.first, it.second)
        }
    }
}
```

And you might want to change the type of the factory parameter from a `<List>Pair` to a `vararg Pair` so it's easier to use.

---

Here's a stripped down example to explain the variance limitation.

Your interface for an Event consumer:

```
interface EventListener<E : Event> {
    fun handle(event: E)
}
```

Two implementations of `Event`:

```
class HelloEvent: Event {
   fun sayHello() = println("Hello world")
}

class BoringEvent: Event {}
```

A class implementing the interface:

```
class HelloEventListener: EventListener<HelloEvent> {
    override fun handle(event: HelloEvent) {
        event.sayHello()
    }
}
```

Now you have an EventListener that can handle **only** `HelloEvent`s. Try to treat it like an `EventListener<Event>`:

```
val eventListener: EventListener<Event> = HelloEventListener() // COMPILE ERROR!
```

Imagine the compiler did not prevent you from doing this and you do this:

```
val eventListener: EventListener<Event> = HelloEventListener()
eventListener.handle(BoringEvent()) // CLASS CAST EXCEPTION AT RUN TIME!
```

If this were allowed your HelloEventListener would try to call `sayHello()` on the BoringEvent, which doesn't have that function, so it will crash. This is what generics are here to protect you from.

Now suppose your `HelloEventListener.handle()` didn't call `event.sayHello()`. Well, then it could have safely handled a BoringEvent. But the compiler isn't doing that level of analysis for you. It just knows what you declared, that HelloEventListener cannot handle anything except HelloEvent.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! One thing I don't get is that when I use event as a the generic type on the parameter, why kotlin is not smart enough to understand that those are all child of Event interface? It seems I can only pass Event type, not subtypes. Is that normal or this happens only in this case for some reason I'm missing?

Comment: This is explained in my first paragraph. It is correctly protecting you from trying to pass classes that can only handle specific children of `Event`. If your EventListener consumes `MyEvent`s, then it cannot safely be treated as a `EventListener<Event>` because then you might pass it an `Event` that is not a `MyEvent` and it will crash with a ClassCastException when it tries to consume the item that it is not equipped to handle.

Comment: yeah what I don't understand is that MyEvent is an Event so I would be happy to add all children of Event and when I get an item back it's ok if is of type Event. If in my example I change the construction by copy pasting the content of the function registerListener instead of invoking it, it all works again. Still confused why? 

Comment: You would only be happy to add all children of Event until you run your app and it crashes. :) It would not be safe for you to pass *any* type of Event to an `EventListener<MyEvent>`. By declaring its type as `MyEvent`, you are declaring that to be the only type of Event it expects to consume. This allows its `handle` method to call functions that only `MyEvent` has, but would also result in a crash if you pass it something like `AnotherEvent`.

Comment: See my update to the answer for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: agreed that's why my interface is EventListener<Event> and not EventListener<MyEvent> where Event is an interface and MyEvent implements Event. maybe I'm missing something but my intent was to talk specialized types when I start implementing the interfaces, like in MyEventListener<MyEvent>

Comment: The solution to doing that is using star projection and casting when you retrieve them, like shown in the first part of my answer. The way you're doing it now is effectively the same as my simplified example where you're telling the compiler to let you treat an `EventHandler<MyEvent>` as an `EventHandler<Event>`. Since this is inherrently unsafe, the compiler forbids it. If you take the extra precautions to prevent it from being used unsafely, like in the first part of my example, then you can use star projection and casting to avoid the compiler restrictions.

Comment: I see what you mean now, so pretty much by using out you are saying to the compiler 'don't worry, I'm just gonna use Event as a return type but I'm never gonna use it to pass it subtypes of Events'

Comment: Yes. I’m this case, `out` let’s you do the same thing star projection would, basically saying you won’t pass it any subtype of Event. Either way, you will have to cast it when you retrieve it to be able to pass it anything.

Comment: gotcha thanks for the explanation! that was what I was about to ask. Why star projection and not "out Event"?

Comment: Either way, you’re ignoring the type. Star projection is just simpler to type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217779/discussion-between-andrea-giuliano-and-tenfour04).